# How to add CSS class name from variable in Angular 9 depends on boolean variable?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-class

I want to add class names from a variable, but it's depends on another variable in Angular 9.

Here is my TypeScript code

```js
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() inputBlockClass = 'col-12 d-flex px-0';
  @Input() inputBlockExtraClass = 'col-md-9';
  @Input() showLabel = true;

  // ...
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<div [class]="inputBlockClass" [class.inputBlockExtraClass]="showLabel">
```

I tried this too, but it's doesn't work:

```html
<div [class]="inputBlockClass" [ngClass]="{inputBlockExtraClass: showLabel}">
```

Both solution give this result:

```html
<div _ngcontent-sxj-c111="" class="col-12 d-flex px-0 inputBlockExtraClass">
```

But I want this:

```html
<div _ngcontent-sxj-c111="" class="col-12 d-flex px-0 col-md-9">
```

How can I add a class name from variable depends on boolean variable?

Comment: I'd remove `[class]` and use `[ngClass]="[inputBlockClass, showLabel ? inputBlockExtraClass : '']"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<div [class]="inputBlockClass" [ngClass]="showLabel ? inputBlockExtraClass : ''">
```

or you can get rid of `[class]`:

```
<div [ngClass]="[inputBlockClass, showLabel ? inputBlockExtraClass : '']">
```

[**STACKBLITZ DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psnfs9)

Comment: your solution of getting rid of class is nice.I learnt something new. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Did you try doing this?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngclass-nbleik

```
 <div [class]="inputBlockClass" [ngClass]="showLabel?inputBlockExtraClass:''">>
      sometext
 </div>
```

Comment: Show some support by upvoting whenever you found it useful ;)